# Einstein as an adjective

Tags: diction

I was writing my college essay and I needed to make my composition to make a bit interesting. Consequently, I should avoid cliché words and word redundancies.

I wanted to get a bit artistic on this sentence:

> Not that I am too genius to ...

I thought 'genius' was too boring and I wanted to replace it with

> Not that I am too einstein to ...

Do you think this is too informal for college essay ? Other word suggestions will also do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The whole construction is questionable.

Comment: You are more familiar with what register is expected by your institution than people here can possibly be.

Comment: As advice for life, I would advise you, in the words of Polonius to his son, Laertes in 'Hamlet':  :to thine own self be true.  Say what you truly have to say without dressing it up.  If you want to use a reference to Einstein, then the natural expression would be:  "...not that I am too much o an Einstein to ...".  But whether it is apt in its  context depends on the wider context, which you have not provided.  Would you?

Comment: One can definitely have an Einstein moment. (If one is sufficiently endowed to think Nobellian thoughts.) Purists might argue for 'Einsteinian' but I prefer the first, myself. It's not an adjective : 'Einstein moment' is a compound noun.